# How do I disable a radio input form control with the rest of the form?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

When I call **this.employeeForm.disable()** inside of the ngOnInit function of my component, all of my form controls become disabled except for the reminder_email, radio button control.  If I place the disable call inside of a setTimeout of even 1 millisecond it works. (entire form is disabled)  I can even get it to work by placing a click handler somewhere on the page to toggle the control between enabled and disabled.  There are numerous hacks that I can apply to make it work but I would prefer to do this the right way.  If you need any more information, ask me in the comments.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CompanyService } from '../../../shared/services/company.service';
import { Employee } from '../../../shared/classes/employee';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-detail',
  templateUrl: './employee-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-detail.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  packages: any = [];
  employee: Employee;
  validationMessages = this.companyService.validationMessages;
  formErrors = this.companyService.formErrors;
  roles = this.companyService.roles;
  employeeForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  active = false;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public companyService: CompanyService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const employeeId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;

    this.companyService.getEmployee(employeeId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.employee = data;
        this.buildForm();
        this.active = true;
        this.employeeForm.disable();
      });

  }

  buildForm(): void {
    this.employeeForm = this.fb.group({
      'firstname': [this.employee.firstname, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.maxLength(24)
      ]
      ],
      'lastname': [this.employee.lastname, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.maxLength(24)
      ]
      ],
      'email': [this.employee.email, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
      ]
      ],
      'date_hired': [this.employee.date_hired, [
        Validators.required,
      ]
      ],
      'title': [this.employee.title, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength,
        Validators.maxLength
      ]
      ],
      'role': [this.employee.role, [
        Validators.required,
      ]
      ],
      'team': [this.employee.team, [

      ]
      ],
      'training_package': [this.employee.training_package, [
        Validators.required,
      ]
      ],
      'reminder_email': [this.employee.reminder_email, [
        Validators.required,
      ]
      ],
    });
};

  saveEmployee() {
    // save employee
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="employeeForm" *ngIf="active" (ngSubmit)="saveEmployee()">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstname" required>
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.firstname" class="alert alert-danger">{{ formErrors.firstname }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lastname" required>
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.lastname" class="alert alert-danger">{{ formErrors.lastname }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" required>
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.email" class="alert alert-danger">{{ formErrors.email }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="dateHired">Hire Date:</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="date_hired" required>
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.date_hired" class="alert alert-danger">{{ formErrors.date_hired }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Title:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="title" required>
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.title" class="alert alert-danger">{{ formErrors.title }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="role">Role:</label>
              <select class="form-control pointer" formControlName="role" required>
            <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [selected]="employee.role.name" [ngValue]="role.value">{{ role.title }}</option>
          </select>
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.title" class="alert alert-danger">{{ formErrors.title }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="team">Team:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="team" [value]="employee.team.name">
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.team" class="alert alert-danger">{{ formErrors.team }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="package">Training Package:</label>
              <select class="form-control pointer" formControlName="training_package" required>
            <option *ngFor="let package of packages" [selected]="employee.training_package.name" [ngValue]="package.id">{{ package.name }}</option>
          </select>
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.package" class="alert alert-danger">{{ formErrors.title }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Send Reminder Emails?</label>
              <br>
              <label for="reminder_email">Yes</label>
              <input [checked]="employee.reminder_email === true" formControlName="reminder_email" type="radio" [value]=true [(ngModel)]="employee.reminder_email">
              <br>
              <label for="reminder_email">No</label>
              <input [checked]="employee.reminder_email === false" formControlName="reminder_email" type="radio" [value]=false [(ngModel)]="employee.reminder_email">
              <br>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>

          </form>
```

Comment: You actually dont' need this `[checked]="employee.reminder_email === false"` and I guess it should be `[ngValue]=true|false`. Not sure but if you remove ngModel binding and remove all stuff that I wrote, will it work?

Comment: I removed the [checked] but it removes the binding to whether or not the employee wants reminder email so nothing is pre-filled.  When I changed [value] to [ngValue] I get a template parse error: Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

Comment: And what about ngModels? It is better to change it from `form.valuesChanges` anyway

Comment: I changed type="radio" to type="checkbox" and it fixes it.  Any idea why?

Comment: There may be a conflict when you don't have employee both `checked` have false. Sorry, have no opportunity to debug this in code.

Comment: Please do not use two way binding together with reactive forms, this is discouraged and mostly causes problems, as a sidenote the ngModel directive is not even included in the `ReactiveFormsModule` :) And why not call to disable form after building the form?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @AJT_82.  I am calling to disable the form after it's built and every form control is being disabled EXCEPT the radio button control for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, I mean call it lastly in the `buildForm()` method. This seems to be a race condition, `this.employeeForm.disable();` seems to be called before the build of the form has completed. We need to remember, that Angular doesn't **wait** for `buildForm()` to be completely executed before executing the code that follows, but continues with the code in `OnInit` right after `buildForm()` has been fired, not when it has completed :)

Comment: This I gather from that it works if you set a timeout, it gives Angular just enough time to complete the build of the form.

Comment: I've done this as well and it does not work. If I move the radio button to the top of the form it does not work.  If I change the radio button to  a select, it works.  I don't understand why the setTimeout works; it appears to be a race condition but no matter where I place the radio button it is always the only control to not be disabled.

Comment: Hmm. Could you possibly try and reproduce it in a plunker?

Comment: I will when I get some free time.

Answer (score 0):

> If I place the disable call inside of a setTimeout of even 1 millisecond it works. (entire form is disabled)

If you place the code inside a ngAfterViewInit it should call after the form has been established.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    const employeeId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;

    this.companyService.getEmployee(employeeId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.employee = data;
        this.buildForm();
        this.active = true;
        this.employeeForm.disable();
      });
}
```

Comment: It is still allowing me to toggle between yes and no.

Comment: Interesting, maybe try ngAfterViewChecked, its next [and also last] in the startup lifecycle. Besides that, I would handle it with a direct bind in the radio buttons.

Comment: Check out my comment above.